# Vertically stacking two arrays of different size without zero-padding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to stack vertically two(1D) arrays of different sizes to form a single 2D-array without making their size same by zero padding.

Like

```
a=np.arange(52)
b=np.arange(62)
and Expected new array should be like:

c=[0 1 2 ......51 52

     0 1 2 ......51 52 ...62]
```

****Actually zero padding effects the other values. I have tried hstack/vstack but these require same dimentions. numpy.append/concatenate give values in same row which is not required****.

Comment: Numpy isn't meant to store jagged arrays.

Comment: What would such an array/matrix represent mathematically? If this is about efficiency: scipy comes with a sparse linalg module

Comment: Maybe you need an array of arrays: c = [a, b]

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann yes it is about accuracy of feature vectors.

Comment: @egur thank u , it helped.